# Actionscript error #1056 in flash game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a flash game and it's showing error in the below code

```
private function onAddingTimer(event:TimerEvent) : void
       {
           var _loc_2:int = 0;
           var _loc_3:MovieClip = null;
           var _loc_4:MovieClip = null;
           var _loc_5:String = this;
           var _loc_6:* = this.timerAddCounter + 1;
           _loc_5.timerAddCounter = _loc_6;
           this.bonusIntervalDiff = int(this.levelData[this.level].enemyCount / this.levelData[this.level].bonusCount);
           if (this.timerAddCounter >= this.levelData[this.level].createDelay)
           {
               var _loc_5:String = this;
               var _loc_6:* = this.timerAddCount + 1;
               _loc_5.timerAddCount = _loc_6;
               if (int(this.timerAddCount % this.bonusIntervalDiff) == 0)
               {
                   _loc_2 = this.rangeRandom(0, this.LIFE_CLASSES.length);
                   trace("Ran:: " + _loc_2);
                   _loc_3 = new this.LIFE_CLASSES[_loc_2].className() as MovieClip;
                   this.spLifeGround.addChild(_loc_3);
                   _loc_3.y = 500;
                   this.previousX = this.rangeRandomWithPreviousDifference(100, 700, 210, this.previousX);
                   _loc_3.x = this.previousX;
                   this.lifes.push({mc:_loc_3, score:this.LIFE_CLASSES[_loc_2].score, cls:this.LIFE_CLASSES[_loc_2].className});
               }
               else
               {
                   _loc_4 = new this.EMENY_CLASSES[this.rangeRandom(0, this.EMENY_CLASSES.length)] as MovieClip;
                   this.spEnemyGround.addChild(_loc_4);
                   _loc_4.y = 450;
                   this.previousX = this.rangeRandomWithPreviousDifference(75, 725, 210, this.previousX);
                   _loc_4.x = this.previousX;
                   this.enemys.push(_loc_4);
               }
               this.timerAddCounter = 0;
           }
           return;
       }// end function
```

Error from the console is

> ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property timerAddCounter on
>   String.
>          at JuegoGame/onAddingTimer()
>          at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
>          at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

Does any know, why it is not working properly.

Comment: this does not look like your own code, rather it's a decompiled code of someone else.

Comment: Because it was protected by obfuscator and decompiled code is not equal to original one?

Answer (score 0):

Because `String` objects in Actionscript 3 don't support dynamically adding variables. You're code is attempting to add the property `timerAddCounter` to a `String` instance.

```
var _loc_5:String = this;
...
_loc_5.timerAddCounter = _loc_6;
```

`_loc_5` must be either a dynamic object, or an object that has a setter for `timeAddCounter`.